# How do I install mdbtools on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rpm, yum, mdbtools

To install `mdbtools` on an EC2 instance I entered the following:

```
curl http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/m/mdbtools-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm > mdbtools-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh mdbtools-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum -q install mdbtools -y
```

but I get the following

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libmdb.so.2()(64bit) is needed by mdbtools-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64
    libmdbsql.so.2()(64bit) is needed by mdbtools-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64
    mdbtools-libs = 0.7.1-3.el7 is needed by mdbtools-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64
```

I have no idea how to fix these on EC2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have access to yum? it may be easier to install via that route to solve the deps.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching a single package directly, then attempting to install it.

The package has a bunch of dependencies that can't be satisfied when it is taken outside a repository context.

What you should do, is install the EPEL repository configuration as detailed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/).

Then let `yum` install the package while picking up whichever dependencies required:

```
yum install mdbtools
```

If for whatever reason, you want to install things without EPEL repository being configured, you will have one fun time fetching all the dependencies, which depends on a particular package :)

In this particular case you need at least `mdbtools-libs`, which direct URL is `https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/m/mdbtools-libs-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm`