# Can I install tools using yum inside AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ms-access, installation, aws-lambda

do you know if there exists a way to use `yum` from inside a Lambda function. For example, I need to install `mdbtools`, but if in my lambda I write (in Python)

```py
subprocess.run(['yum', 'install', 'mdbtools'])
```

then it says

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yum'
```

I also tried with

```py
os.system('yum install mdbtools')
```

but it says

```
sh: yum: command not found
```

Finally, I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857529/how-do-i-install-mdbtools-on-an-ec2-instance) to enable also the EPEL repository, so I tried with

```py
os.system('sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y; sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel; yum install mdbtools')
os.system('sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y; sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel; yum install mdbtools')
os.system('sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y; sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel; yum install mdbtools')
```

but again I get

```
sh: sudo: command not found
sh: sudo: command not found
sh: yum: command not found
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your lambda zip should include all dependencies.

Comment: The file system in the Lambda environment is read-only, so even if `yum` was available, it wouldn't be able to install anything.

Answer (score 2):

If `yum` existed in the Lambda environment, it should be in `/bin/yum`. I've looked there, and don't see it, so I'm going to assume that you won't be able to run it.

If you need a library that can't be packaged in a deployment bundle, you'll need to use a [Lambda Container Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). Start with one of the pre-built base images, and run `yum` in your `Dockerfile`.

*However,* I see that you've tagged this question with `ms-access`. If you're trying to install a Microsoft product in a the Linix-based Lambda environment, you'll need to do a lot more than just run `yum`.

Comment: Note that this is only true for AL2-based installs. As of Amazon Linux 2023 it's fedora-based and yum disappears (presumably to be replaced with dnf but this also seems to be broken on at least some of the preview versions).

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** how it is intended to work with dependencies in Lambdas.

It can be achieved in another way though.
You should include all the libs and dependencies in your .zip file which you upload. More information on that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/).

Comment: You use yum to install system libraries, which can't be packaged in a deployment bundle.

Comment: I get that, but this is not what Lambda is intended for. There is the possibility though, to include yum packages as written in the linked post.